# Populating a f.select of day names that relate to the last 6 days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to populate a f.select with the last 6 days using day names. I want the field presented by their day names but internally I want to save the date previous to NOW that the day name represents.

```
@days = [ ] 

6.downto(0).each do |number| 
   @days << number.days.ago 
end
```

This will give me the last days which is the data I want to be able to select to save.
I want the select field populated with those dates, but with the day names only.
If I do this....

```
@days.each do |d| 
  @daynumber = d.wday 
end
```

Then I get ...

> Date::DAYNAMES[@daynumber]
>
> ..... ERROR..It cant implicitly convert array into integer.

No clue.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you need to iterate over that array to get the dayname lookup to work. Luckily, Ruby has awesome built-in methods to do exactly that, and `Enumerable#map` is perhaps the most useful.

Try this:

```
>> @days.map { |d| Date::DAYNAMES[d.wday] }
=> ["Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
```

Or if you don't need the interim array for some other reason, you can do the whole thing in a single line like this:

```
>> day_names = 6.downto(0).map { |number| Date::DAYNAMES[number.days.ago.wday] }
=> ["Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm not quite there yet. On my form to select the days I would like to save the date format. So I tried this... f.select :backup, @days.map { |d| Date::DAYNAMES[d.wday] }. It saves a date in a date format but no matter the selection, it saves only todays date and not the selected date that refers to the dayname selected. Am I doing the form wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out while researching map and collect.

```
<%= f.select :backup, @days.collect { |d| [ Date::DAYNAMES[d.wday], d ] }   %>
```

This is working! Thank you community for helping me correct my question and pointing towards an answer.